# Getting Error When Building My App

Tags: android, android-studio

When i build my app it gives and error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/DebugUtils.class

I tried:
Cleaning and re-building my app but not working....

Comment: Is it resolved your issue.

Comment: I have same issue,
I clean my project and also rebuild

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

This error is due to the duplicate entry of  **android/support/v4** library.

If not solve then delete the **android.support.v4 jar** from the **lib** folder.